# How can I vertically center side-by-side anchor and anchor-image tags?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am having trouble centering these two elements. I'm not sure what my problem is. Hopefully someone can help me out. 
First here is an screenshot of what is going on:

[image]

So how do I get these elements vertically centered?

Here is my HTML and CSS:

```
<div class="vcenter">
<p>
<a href="http://www.google.com">JimDaniel</a>
<a href="http://www.cnn.com"><img src="icon.png"/></a>
</p>
</div>

.vcenter
{
    padding:10px;
    background-color:darkBlue;
    min-height: 25px;   
    display: table-cell;   
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you mean you want the text centered in the middle of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

http://jsbin.com/opifu5

```
.vcenter img {
    vertical-align: top
}
```